# TableView doesn't reload in the textViewShouldEndEditing method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I am making an app which uses tableView having TextView as a Cell in it. And it adds more cell on click of footer of the tableView.

Now i want to reload table when textView done the editing.For that i put the [tblView reloadData] in textViewShouldEndEditing but at this time table doesn't reload.

Please help me.

Comment: Please post your relevant code.

Comment: what you tried?can you post your relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to verify that the textView.delegate is set to an instance of the class that implements textViewShouldEndEditing.  If the TextView is in a UITableViewCell subclass, then you might be setting that subclass as the delegate for the UITextView, when in fact you've implemented the delegate methods on the view controller that contains the tableView.

One approach would be this:

1. Put your UITextView in a UITableViewCell subclass.
2. Implement the UITextViewDelegate methods in your view controller that contains the UITableView. (Which may, in itself, be a UITableViewController, but it could just be a UIViewController that has a UITableView in it; either one is fine.)
3. Make a relationship between the cell and the containing view controller using code similar to this:

---

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCustomCellSubclass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier....];
    cell.textView.delegate = self;
    // do further cell customization if needed
    return cell;
    }
```

Then when your cell's textView finishes, it'll call back to the containing view controller.

Also, from your description, it sounds like you might prefer the delegate method:
  `- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView;`
instead of "shouldEndEditing", but for what you're describing, that isn't your current problem.

As an added tip, if you do `[tblView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewAnimationRowAutomatic]`, it'll refresh the tableview using a nice little animation, instead of a hard reload like reloadData does.

Comment: Thanks Woodster I have applied [tblView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewAnimationRowAutomatic] in textViewDidEndEditing. And it works fine for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `UITextView` `Delegate Methods` are calling by putting `NSLog` `try` with using following `Delegate Method` of `UITextView`.

```
-(void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    [self performSelector:@selector(reloadTableViewData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
}

- (void)reloadTableViewData {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but in this case my tableView got stuck when I am trying to switch between textView to edit them.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for your answers.
But I have tried [tblView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]  in textViewDidEndEditing.
And it fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure you have UITextView Delegate for the self View. Like

```
UITextView.delegate = self ;
```

After that in

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextView *)theTextField {
if (theTextField == TextView) {
    [Tableview Reload];
}
return YES;
```

}

Try this , Let me know.